# Conjecture: three or more decompositions into powers with a base differing by 1 means its a perfect power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, natural-numbers, conjectures, integers

If

$$(i_1)^{a_1}(i_1+1)^{b_1}=n $$
$$(i_2)^{a_2}(i_2+1)^{b_2}=n $$
$$(i_3)^{a_3}(i_3+1)^{b_3}=n $$

where all the terms are positive integers and the groups $(i_1,a_1,b_1),(i_2,a_2,b_2),(i_3,a_3,b_3)$ are different (i.e. $n$ is being decomposed in 3 different ways) *then*  $n$ is a perfect power, i.e. it is expressible in the form $j^c = n$, where $c>1$.

I have tested this up to $10^{14}$ and not found a counterexample.  Furthermore, I have never found an integer which can be expressed like this in four ways, i.e. with the addition of $(i_4)^{a_4}(i_4+1)^{b_4}=n$.

**Is it generally true, and if so can it be proved?**

*Examples*
$$576=2^{6}.3^{2}=3^{2}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{1}$$
$$5184=2^{6}.3^{4}=3^{4}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{2}$$
$$36864=2^{12}.3^{2}=3^{2}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{1}$$
$$46656=2^{6}.3^{6}=3^{6}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{3}$$
$$331776=2^{12}.3^{4}=3^{4}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{2}$$
$$419904=2^{6}.3^{8}=3^{8}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{4}$$
$$810000=5^{4}.6^{4}=9^{2}.10^{4}=15^{4}.16^{1}$$
$$2359296=2^{18}.3^{2}=3^{2}.4^{9}=8^{6}.9^{1}$$
$$2985984=2^{12}.3^{6}=3^{6}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{3}$$
$$3779136=2^{6}.3^{10}=3^{10}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{5}$$
$$16003008=6^{6}.7^{3}=27^{2}.28^{3}=63^{3}.64^{1}$$
$$21233664=2^{18}.3^{4}=3^{4}.4^{9}=8^{6}.9^{2}$$
$$26873856=2^{12}.3^{8}=3^{8}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{4}$$
$$34012224=2^{6}.3^{12}=3^{12}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{6}$$
$$150994944=2^{24}.3^{2}=3^{2}.4^{12}=8^{8}.9^{1}$$
$$191102976=2^{18}.3^{6}=3^{6}.4^{9}=8^{6}.9^{3}$$
$$241864704=2^{12}.3^{10}=3^{10}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{5}$$
$$306110016=2^{6}.3^{14}=3^{14}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{7}$$
$$1358954496=2^{24}.3^{4}=3^{4}.4^{12}=8^{8}.9^{2}$$
$$1719926784=2^{18}.3^{8}=3^{8}.4^{9}=8^{6}.9^{4}$$
$$2176782336=2^{12}.3^{12}=3^{12}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{6}$$
$$2754990144=2^{6}.3^{16}=3^{16}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{8}$$
$$9663676416=2^{30}.3^{2}=3^{2}.4^{15}=8^{10}.9^{1}$$
$$12230590464=2^{24}.3^{6}=3^{6}.4^{12}=8^{8}.9^{3}$$
$$15479341056=2^{18}.3^{10}=3^{10}.4^{9}=8^{6}.9^{5}$$
$$19591041024=2^{12}.3^{14}=3^{14}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{7}$$
$$24794911296=2^{6}.3^{18}=3^{18}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{9}$$
$$86973087744=2^{30}.3^{4}=3^{4}.4^{15}=8^{10}.9^{2}$$
$$110075314176=2^{24}.3^{8}=3^{8}.4^{12}=8^{8}.9^{4}$$
$$139314069504=2^{18}.3^{12}=3^{12}.4^{9}=8^{6}.9^{6}$$
$$176319369216=2^{12}.3^{16}=3^{16}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{8}$$
$$223154201664=2^{6}.3^{20}=3^{20}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{10}$$
$$618475290624=2^{36}.3^{2}=3^{2}.4^{18}=8^{12}.9^{1}$$
$$656100000000=5^{8}.6^{8}=9^{4}.10^{8}=15^{8}.16^{2}$$
$$782757789696=2^{30}.3^{6}=3^{6}.4^{15}=8^{10}.9^{3}$$
$$990677827584=2^{24}.3^{10}=3^{10}.4^{12}=8^{8}.9^{5}$$
$$1253826625536=2^{18}.3^{14}=3^{14}.4^{9}=8^{6}.9^{7}$$
$$1586874322944=2^{12}.3^{18}=3^{18}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{9}$$
$$2008387814976=2^{6}.3^{22}=3^{22}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{11}$$
$$5566277615616=2^{36}.3^{4}=3^{4}.4^{18}=8^{12}.9^{2}$$
$$7044820107264=2^{30}.3^{8}=3^{8}.4^{15}=8^{10}.9^{4}$$
$$8916100448256=2^{24}.3^{12}=3^{12}.4^{12}=8^{8}.9^{6}$$
$$11284439629824=2^{18}.3^{16}=3^{16}.4^{9}=8^{6}.9^{8}$$
$$14281868906496=2^{12}.3^{20}=3^{20}.4^{6}=8^{4}.9^{10}$$
$$18075490334784=2^{6}.3^{24}=3^{24}.4^{3}=8^{2}.9^{12}$$
$$39582418599936=2^{42}.3^{2}=3^{2}.4^{21}=8^{14}.9^{1}$$
$$50096498540544=2^{36}.3^{6}=3^{6}.4^{18}=8^{12}.9^{3}$$
$$63403380965376=2^{30}.3^{10}=3^{10}.4^{15}=8^{10}.9^{5}$$
$$80244904034304=2^{24}.3^{14}=3^{14}.4^{12}=8^{8}.9^{7}$$

Comment: How many examples of $n$ did you find which were not of the form $2^a3^b$?

Comment: For the sake of completeness: I think you assume that all the $i_j,a_j,b_j$ are greater than $1$. Is that so?

Comment: @jflipp no they can be 1, as the example of 6480 shows.

Comment: Paul Richards: neither $6480$ nor $9702$ have triple cases

Comment: @Henry $810000 = 6^4.5^4 = 9^2.10^4 = 15^4.16^1$, so its not of the form $2^a.3^b$, it has 5 in its prime factors

Comment: Can you post a link to the set of integers that have such a representation that you have found? (Or just the ones that have factors other than 2 and 3?) Or just add the list to the OP if it's not too long.

Comment: To fleshen out all those comments about the case $2^a3^b$: If $n$ has no prime divisor $>3$, the candidates for $(i,i+1)$ are $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(3,4)$, and $(8,9)$, period. Since three of the pairs occur, one of $(3,4)$, $(8,9)$ must occur. Then $6\mid n$ and  $(1,2)$ is no longer possible and hence 
$$ n=2^{a_1}3^{b_1}=3^{a_2}4^{b_2}=8^{a_3}9^{b_3}.$$
This is equivalent to saying $a_1=2b_2=3a_3$ and $b_1=a_2=2b_3$, i.e. $a_1$ is a multiple of $6$ and $b_1$ is even, thus making $n = (2^{a_2}3^{b_3})^2$.

Comment: @rogerl I have appended all the known examples (up to $10^{14}$) to the OP.

Comment: All the examples so far have 2 and 3 as prime factors, and additionally some have one other distinct prime factor: either 5 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: Suppose that $n$ is so representable but has only two distinct prime factors $p$ and $q$. Then $n=i^{a_1}(i+1)^{b_1}$, and $i$ must be a power of $p$ (say) and $i+1$ a power of $q$.

Suppose first that $i\ne p$ and $i+1\ne q$. Then by Catalan's conjecture we must have $i=8$ and $i+1=9$, so that $p=2$ and $q=3$. Thus $n = 8^{a_1}9^{b_1} = 2^{3a_1}3^{2b_1}$. For $n$ to have a third representation, the only possibility (Catalan's conjecture again) is $4^{3a_1/2}3^{2a_2}$. Thus $a_1$ must be even, so that $n = 2^{3a_1}3^{2b_1}$ is a perfect square.

Alternatively suppose $i=p$. Then $i+1$ must be a power of $q$ that is one greater than $p$, which is impossible unless $p=2$ and $q=3$, which again is covered above.

Finally, if $i+1=q$, then $q-1$ is a power of $p$, which is again impossible unless $p=2$ and $q=3$.

So any $n$ satisfying the condition having a prime factor greater than $3$ must have at least three distinct primes in its factorization.